# How to parse empty values from a csv file and initialize to a default value in c#?

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to read data from a `CSV` file but my `CSV` file has lot of empty cells for various columns. So, I would like to capture those empty cells and initialize those empty values to default value `-1`. I tried to loop through the values but for some reason it partly works and partly doesn't. What could I be doing wrong?

```
//Some of the columns are still empty even though they were supposed to 
//initialized to -1. While some others are initialized to -1.

public class DPdfView
{
    public DPdfView()
    {
        //ReadExcel("t.csv");
    }

    public String ReadCSV()
    {
        String cont = null;
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser("t.csv"))
        {
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                //Processing row
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fields[i].Length == 0)
                    {
                        fields[i] = "\n" + "-1";
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(fields[4]);
                }
                String Value_DATE = fields[2];
                String Booking_Date = fields[3];
                String Transaction = fields[4];
                String Reference = fields[7];
                String Money_Out = fields[8];
                String Money_In = fields[9];
                String Balance = fields[14];
                cont = cont + Value_DATE + "\n" + Booking_Date + "\n" + Transaction + "\n" + Reference + "\n" + Money_Out + "\n" + Money_In + "\n" + Balance;
            }
        }
        return cont;
    }
}
```

//As per m.rogalski's suggestions this is what I get. The -1 gets appended to the same line instead of getting appended to the next line.

```
VALUE_DATE
BOOKING_DATE
TRANSACTION
REFERENCE
MONEY.OUT
MONEY.IN
AVAILABLE.BALANCE-1 // the -1 should be appended to the next line
2847899
KES
-1
10/10/2016
9/11/2016
5403.759/11/2016
9/11/2016
Opening Balance
-1
-1
-1
-112/10/2016
12/10/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
1533
-1
-117-10-2016
17-10-2016
ATM Withdrawal
6.29006E+11
1000
-1
-117-10-2016
17-10-2016
ATM Withdrawal
6.29118E+11
2000
-1
-117-10-2016
17-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
2083
-1
-117-10-2016
17-10-2016
Transfer from Mpesa
-1
0
4000
-118-10-2016
18-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
333
-1
-118-10-2016
18-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
733
-1
-121-10-2016
21-10-2016
ATM Withdrawal
5.04158E+15
1000
-1
-121-10-2016
21-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
433
-1
-121-10-2016
21-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
883
-1
-121-10-2016
21-10-2016
Transfer from Mpesa
-1
0
5000
-124-10-2016
24-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
1583
-1
-124-10-2016
24-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
2033
-1
-125-10-2016
25-10-2016
Mobile Internal Transfer
-1
10000
-1
-125-10-2016
25-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
2033
-1
-125-10-2016
25-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
373
-1
-125-10-2016
25-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
50983
-1
-127-10-2016
27-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
1183
-1
-128-10-2016
28-10-2016
ATM Withdrawal
5.04158E+15
20000
-1
-128-10-2016
28-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
1333
-1
-131-10-2016
31-10-2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
783
-1
-11/11/2016
1/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
4533
-1
-11/11/2016
1/11/2016
Transfer from Mpesa
-1
0
3650
-12/11/2016
2/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
833
-1
-13/11/2016
3/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
2033
-1
-14/11/2016
4/11/2016
ATM Withdrawal
5.04158E+15
3000
-1
-14/11/2016
4/11/2016
Mobile Internal Transfer
-1
0
3000
-14/11/2016
4/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
10033
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Airtime Puchase
-1
150
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
1183
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
12283
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
1498
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
283
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
333
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
5033
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
568
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
733
-1
-17/11/2016
7/11/2016
Transfer from Mpesa
-1
0
20100
-18/11/2016
8/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
2033
-1
-18/11/2016
8/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
383
-1
-18/11/2016
8/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
6533
-1
-18/11/2016
8/11/2016
Mobile Mpesa Transfer
-1
938
-1
-18/11/2016
8/11/2016
Transfer from Mpesa
-1
0
14000
-19/11/2016
9/11/2016
Closing Balance
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail ***what is not working*** and what is the intended outcome, just stating that "partly works" doesn't tell much.

Comment: if it's what i think it is, fields[X] + "" (empty string) should do the trick

Comment: @Stavm:- I dint understand. Can you kindly explain the change. I should make?

Comment: you are missing `\n` at the end : `... + Balance + "\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your'e assuming that empty means no signs at all. There can still be signs like `CR`, `LF` or many others.

Try this approach :

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fields[i])) // (fields[i].Length == 0)
{
    fields[i] = string.Format("{0}-1", Environment.NewLine);
}
```

[Online check](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HInF3p)

Comment: @m.rogalski- Thanks. I tried your approach but this is what.i found( the "-1" gets appended to the same line instead of the next line) -

Comment: @m.rogalski- I have updated the results I found if I try the above approach.

Comment: @jessica can you post some example input and desired output? it would be much easier.

Comment: Can you kindly have a look at the sample output that I get?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing...

```
if (fields[i].Length == 0)
{
    fields[i] = "\n" + "-1";
}
```

with..

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fields[i])) {
    fields[i] = "-1";
}
```